# Unable to click on the search bar using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, searchbar

```
public void searchToolbox()
{
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", (By.xpath("//*[@id='twotabsearchtextbox']")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='twotabsearchtextbox']")).sendKeys("Toolbox");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='nav-search']/form/div[2]/div/input")).click();
}
```

This is the code I am trying to use where I want to click on the search box and enter the text "Toolbox" and then click on the Search button. However after opening the page, nothing happens.
Please help.

Comment: what is the error that you are getting.

Comment: Why are you using `JavascriptExecutor` to issue the click on the element with `@id='twotabsearchtextbox'`? Also, no debug is possible with the information at hand... please provide the error traceback, or the logs of your test run.